# Adjusting screen brightness requires sudo

Tags: brightness

I have the issue, that after waking up from suspend, I often can't change the screen brightness via the fn buttons. Installing brightnessctl and trying to adjust the brightness via command line told me, that it requires sudo. With sudo it worked. The behavior led me to the suspicion, that it is caused by missing group memberships. Which are these?

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with regolith-desktop (i3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your user to video group and restart:

```
usermod -aG video ${USER}
```

Reference: https://github.com/Hummer12007/brightnessctl/issues/63

Comment: Hello new user. Thanks for your well formed answer. I switched to regolith 2.0 by now and that solved the problem. But an answer is always better for other people with a similar problem.